# Show that uniform continuity is not the same as continuity.

Tags: real-analysis

I have an exercise that states

> Show that uniform continuity is not the same as continuity.

How would you interpret this exercise? I mean, the definitions are not the same, and they are not equivalent. Would it be enough to prove that a continuous function not necessarily is uniformly continious and hence uniform continous is not the same as continous?

I believe the problem might come from that English is not my native language.

Comment: Give an example of a continuous function that is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this pdf, it explains everything in detail :)

https://www.math.wisc.edu/~robbin/521dir/cont.pdf